# Is there a way to access WordPress logged user from another asp.net site?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

I have 2 totally separate sites, first is WordPress, and second is asp.net. I need when a user open asp.net website, check if he didn't logged in WordPress site, redirect to login form of WordPress.

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: I don't need user info, I want only know he logged or not.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Call Api To Asp.net After User Logged Action And Loggout Acction
With The Below Code
you can use this code in your functions.php  At Your Active Theme

```
<?php
function your_function( $user_login, $user ) {
    // your code
    // Clall APi To Asp.net -> User Logged IN  
}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function', 10, 2);
?>
```

For Logout, You Can Call Another API

```
function wpdocs_redirect_after_logout() {
 
     $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
  // Your Api Code Here 
 
 }
 add_action( 'wp_logout', 'wpdocs_redirect_after_logout' );
```